# Trouble Using Color Scheme in NeoVim

Tags: colorscheme, neovim, iterm2

I don't have a full understanding of how my color scheme is interacting with the `term` setting in vim and this is impeding my ability to get it to display correctly in neovim.

In my .vimrc file, correct behavior of the color scheme in question requires setting

```
set term=xterm
set t_Co=256
```

Omitting either of those settings results in incorrect display of the color scheme:

*correct*
[image: Correct Color Display]
*incorrect*
[image: Incorrect Color Display]
*different incorrect*
[image: Different Incorrect Color Display]

The scheme looks like this:

```
set background=dark
hi clear
if exists("syntax_on")
    syntax reset
endif
let g:colors_name="impact3"

if exists("g:impact_transbg")
    hi Normal       ctermfg=255 ctermbg=none
    hi NonText      ctermfg=DarkGray  ctermbg=none

    hi Statement    ctermfg=Blue      ctermbg=none
    hi Comment      ctermfg=DarkGray  ctermbg=none cterm=bold term=bold
    hi Constant     ctermfg=173  ctermbg=none
    hi Identifier   ctermfg=Cyan      ctermbg=none
    hi Type         ctermfg=DarkGreen ctermbg=none
    hi Folded       ctermfg=0 ctermbg=235 cterm=underline term=none
    hi Special      ctermfg=Blue      ctermbg=none
    hi PreProc      ctermfg=LightGray ctermbg=none cterm=bold term=bold
    hi Scrollbar    ctermfg=Blue      ctermbg=none
    hi Cursor       ctermfg=white     ctermbg=none
    hi ErrorMsg     ctermfg=Red       ctermbg=none cterm=bold term=bold
    hi WarningMsg   ctermfg=Yellow    ctermbg=none
    hi VertSplit    ctermfg=0     ctermbg=0
    hi Directory    ctermfg=Cyan      ctermbg=DarkBlue
    hi Visual       ctermfg=White     ctermbg=Gray cterm=underline term=none
    hi Title        ctermfg=255     ctermbg=Blue
    hi String       ctermfg=Blue   ctermbg=none

    hi StatusLine   term=bold cterm=bold,underline ctermfg=White ctermbg=Black
    hi StatusLineNC term=bold cterm=bold,underline ctermfg=Gray  ctermbg=Black
    hi LineNr       term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=2 ctermbg=None
    hi Search       ctermfg=Black ctermbg=2
    hi TabLine      ctermfg=0 ctermbg=DarkGray
    hi TabLineFill  ctermfg=DarkGray ctermbg=DarkGray
else
    hi Normal       ctermfg=White ctermbg=Black
    hi NonText      ctermfg=DarkGray  ctermbg=Black

    hi Statement    ctermfg=Blue      ctermbg=Black
    hi Comment      ctermfg=DarkGray  ctermbg=Black cterm=bold term=bold
    hi Constant     ctermfg=DarkCyan  ctermbg=Black
    hi Identifier   ctermfg=Cyan      ctermbg=Black
    hi Type         ctermfg=DarkGreen ctermbg=Black
    hi Folded       ctermfg=DarkGreen ctermbg=Black cterm=underline term=none
    hi Special      ctermfg=Blue      ctermbg=Black
    hi PreProc      ctermfg=LightGray ctermbg=Black cterm=bold term=bold
    hi Scrollbar    ctermfg=Blue      ctermbg=Black
    hi Cursor       ctermfg=white     ctermbg=Black
    hi ErrorMsg     ctermfg=Red       ctermbg=Black cterm=bold term=bold
    hi WarningMsg   ctermfg=Yellow    ctermbg=Black
    hi VertSplit    ctermfg=White     ctermbg=Black
    hi Directory    ctermfg=Cyan      ctermbg=DarkBlue
    hi Visual       ctermfg=White     ctermbg=DarkGray cterm=underline term=none
    hi Title        ctermfg=White     ctermbg=DarkBlue

    hi StatusLine   term=bold cterm=bold,underline ctermfg=White ctermbg=Black
    hi StatusLineNC term=bold cterm=bold,underline ctermfg=Gray  ctermbg=Black
    hi LineNr       term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=White ctermbg=Black
endif
```

In neovim, `term` cannot be set. I tried invoking neovim with a manually set $TERM like so:

```
TERM=xterm nvim
```

This produced the correct display of colors in regular vim (i.e. equivalent to setting term in .vimrc), but in neovim it looks like this:

[image]

**Why is the combination of `set term=xterm` and `set t_Co=256` necessary to produce the correct display of this color scheme in vim and why does the equivalent combination of settings produce a different result in neovim?**

*Edit:*

*The default is* `$TERM=xterm256-color`, *which for some reason has to be overridden to `xterm` in regular vim to make the color display correctly. With the environment variable at the 256 default, neovim looks like this:*

[image]

*This is identical to regular vim with `xterm256-color`, but not as intended. My goal is to understand why the xterm hack is necessary/working in vim, and why it doesn't look the same in neovim.*

*Note that many of the colors appear correctly with the above term env variable setting, notable exceptions being line numbers and background. I suspect that the way the colors are specified in this specific color scheme may be involved.*

Comment: Your $TERM is already set to what is generally considered 'correct' on modern systems - 256-color enabled. So the t_Co option, which is normally for compatibility with older terminals, shouldn't be necessary. What if you comment out both configuration lines?

Comment: @David Commenting out both config lines looks the same as commenting out `set term=xterm`.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the iTerm color configuration that you use when the theme is rendered correctly as well as the output from running [this script](https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes/blob/master/tools/screenshotTable.sh)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Main Issue

The main problem you are experiencing is caused by the ordering of the
commands in your `.vimrc`.

You set the `g:impact_transbg` variable *after* you load the colorscheme, and
so the variable does *not* exist when checked by the colorscheme's `if` statement, and
the second version of the colorscheme (in the `else` block) is used.

To fix, you simply need to move the line that sets the variable above the line
where you load the colorscheme:

```
let g:impact_transbg=1
colorscheme impact3
```

You can (and should!) then remove the unnecessary lines from your `.vimrc`:

```
set term=xterm
set background=dark
set t_Co=256
```

### Other Issues

I can also clear up a few other misconceptions/confusions you might have about
how this all works:

#### Explaining the behaviour of `'term'` & `'t_Co'`

Your $TERM is set to `xterm256-color`. Vim reads this, and queries terminfo (or
termcap) to find out how many colours the terminal supports, and then sets
`'t_Co'` accordingly. Presuming your $TERM is correct (yours is) and your
terminfo database contains the correct information for that terminal (yours
does) you should *never* need to manually reset `'t_Co'`.

However, you are then manually setting Vim's `'term'` to xterm. Your terminfo tells
Vim that this terminal only supports 8 colours, so adding this will cause
`'t_Co'` to be incorrectly set to 8. You are manually setting `'t_Co'` *back* to
256, but if you had left the `'term'` setting at the correct value, you would
not have needed to.

Incidentally, when you change `'t_Co'` manually after setting `g:impact_transbg`, it
causes the colorscheme to be reloaded (to allow the colorscheme to adapt to the
new number of colours), and because `g:impact_transbg` *is* now set, you get the
colours you desire.

(With the line setting `'term'` omitted, `'t_Co'` is *already* set to 256 when you get
to the latter line in your .vimrc, and so the colorscheme is not reloaded: hence
wrong colours.)

So, to recap:

```
term=xterm
colorscheme impact3
let g:impact_transbg=1
set t_Co=256
```

Result: Colorscheme is reloaded when `'t_Co'` is set to 256, colours are correct.

```
"term=xterm
colorscheme impact3
let g:impact_transbg=1
set t_Co=256
```

Result: Colorscheme is loaded by `colorscheme` command, variable does not exist,
colours are wrong.

```
term=xterm
colorscheme impact3
let g:impact_transbg=1
"set t_Co=256
```

Result: Colorscheme is loaded by `colorscheme` command, variable does not exist
and Vim only uses 8 colours, colours are wrong.

```
"term=xterm
colorscheme impact3
let g:impact_transbg=1
"set t_Co=256
```

Result: Colorscheme is loaded by `colorscheme` command, variable does not exist,
colours are wrong.

```
let g:impact_transbg=1
colorscheme impact3
```

Result: Colorscheme is loaded by `colorscheme` command, variable *does* exist, so colours are correct. (And as a bonus `'term'` and `'t_Co'` are also correct!)

The behaviour is different in NeoVim simply because the call to set `'t_Co'` is ignored, as other answerers have already mentioned.

#### `'background'`

After setting the colorscheme, you also set `'background'`. For this *particular*
colorscheme, this is completely unnecessary, because the first thing the
colorscheme does is to set `'background'` to `'dark'`.

Note that I disagree with the other answerer who suggests that you should set
`'background'` after loading your colorscheme. The colorscheme may use the value
of `'background'` to adjust its colors, so setting `'background'` before loading
the colorscheme is the more obvious ordering. (Although note that if you change
the `'background'` setting, Vim will reload any loaded colorschemes, so setting
it `'background'` afterwards would also work: it's just non-optimal.)

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely thorough and I appreciate the additional context.

Comment: @ConradMeyer I’m glad it was helpful for you!

Answer (score 7):

In the case of Neovim, `t_Co` and `TERM` make no difference.

You are calling `set background=dark`before *and* after the call to `colorscheme impact3`. Move `set background=dark` to the bottom of the colorscheme, and *remove* the other call from your vimrc.

From `:help 'background'`:

```
When 'background' is set Vim will adjust the default color 
groups for the new value.
...
When a color scheme is loaded (the "g:colors_name" variable 
is set) setting 'background' will cause the color scheme to 
be reloaded.
```

See also: https://github.com/justinmk/molokai/commit/aa1cc201c743dd7d1b80bb2e2b5fbb7894ebfe5f

> My goal is to understand why the xterm hack is necessary/working in vim, and why it doesn't look the same in neovim.

- Neovim doesn't care about `t_Co` because it assumes 256 unless you [enable "true color"](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-use-true-color-in-the-terminal).

  - In fact Neovim ignores all `t_*` options, see `:help t_xx`.
- Neovim doesn't allow `&term` to be set because it is meaningless. Neovim uses [unibilium](https://github.com/mauke/unibilium) and other mechanisms to detect terminal capabilities.

Comment: thanks a lot for your insights regarding neovim term capability detection and  ` t_*` settings. Removing the redundant copy of and repositioning the `set background=dark` statement didn't have an effect, but those details about the underlying implementation are much more valuable to me.

Answer (score 2):

I see you use iTerm2, so you can try this:

1. Open prefernces window <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
2. Go to `profiles` tab
3. Check your current profile in the left list
4. Click on the tab `terminal` at right
5. In the `Report terminal type` choose `xterm-256color`
6. Done.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited the above with remarks regarding `xterm-256color`. I followed through with your procedure to find terminal type already set thus.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an awesome NeoVim feature. There's an env var that helps with this stuff. Try putting this in your nvimrc:

```
let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1 " True gui colors in terminal
```

Or

```
export NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
```

in the shell.

Comment: FYI: this will require the use of `guifg` and `guibg`. OP's colorscheme uses `ctermfg` and `ctermbg`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up options

```
let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1 
set termguicolors
```

in your `.config/nvim/init.vim`.

Comment: Those options are for using `guifg` and `guibg` RGB values for color.  The question's color scheme only uses `ctermfg` and `ctermbg`.

Comment: This did it for me. TERM was already xterm-256color. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the specific color scheme is really two sets of color schemes within an if-else clause. The existence of the variable`g:impact_transbg` selects the desired set of colors, and was originally intended to account for transparent backgrounds in the color scheme from which this is [derived](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1326).

Commenting out the 2nd color scheme and the if-else statement (leaving only the desired color scheme and doing away with `g:impact_transbg`) yields the intended behavior in both vim and neovim even with `set term=xterm` and `set t_Co=256` removed.

This implies that with `$TERM=xterm-256colors` in both vim and neovim, the conditional `if exists("g:impact_transbg")` fails, but that the combination of setting

```
set term=xterm
set t_co=256
```

allowed the conditional to succeed. **Removing the if-else clause** as described above solves the material issue, but there's still a mystery regarding the interaction between the pair of .vimrc term settings and `g:impact_transbg`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `$TERM`environment variable like this:

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

Also try starting nvim like this:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color; nvim
```

If that works, set the `$TERM` variable in your shell permanently.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Jeff. I edited my question with remarks regarding `xterm-256color`. Setting $TERM via export had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently with the solarized theme. The problem did come from the `TERM` env variable.

I fixed it by telling my terminal emulator (terminator in my case) to run `env TERM=xterm-256color zsh` instead of just starting up zsh as normal.

Comment: The OPs TERM is already set to xterm-256color. I think you were experiencing a different issue.